# p:toolbar not displaying, although other elements are working fine

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have below code to display an editor and toolbar, somehow toolbar is not displaying and I am just getting a big thin line (yellow highlighted in screenshot).

I used the toolbar code from here.

Could someone please help me point out the issue, I search and see that jquery could be issue but I am not loading any jquery or other library explicitly. Also, my editor is working fine but not toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>

        <p:editor></p:editor>

        <br></br>

        <p:toolbar>
        <f:facet name="left">
            <p:commandButton type="button" title="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" title="Delete" icon="ui-icon-trash" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" title="Print" icon="ui-icon-print" />
        </f:facet>


    </p:toolbar>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to state your PF version  (and always good to state the JSF version and impl too)

Answer (score 1):

I cloned the PrimeFaces Test Project: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Entered your exact code above into `test.xhtml`.

I then then ran the project with `mvn clean jetty:run` and navigated to http://localhost:8080/primefaces-test/test.xhtml

And here is my my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to state with which PF version you tried this (and always good to state the JSF version and impl too)

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using Prime Faces 4.0 with MyFaces 2.0 and running on Tomcat 7.8

Comment: @Melloware: Thank you for your time check, do you have any idea why this isn't working for me? Can you try on Tomcat 7.8 and Apache MyFaces 2.0 ... Meanwhile I will try to check if there is any local CSS which is causing this issue, but should not be the case because in my HTML I am not including anything.

Comment: Or your  PF version does not support a toolbar with facet. Tried without?